# Action Script 3: Problems with gotoAndStop() after a Movie Clip

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, goto

Upon the click of a button, an animation starts. Then the program directs you to a certain frame when the animation is done.

Is this possible?

So this is what I've got so far: a Movie Clip `movQuizIntro` and a Button `btnBond` in Frame 1.

```
stop()
movQuizIntro.stop()

btnBond.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BondQuiz)
btnReg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Registrering)

function BondQuiz (evt:MouseEvent)
{
    if (currentFrame == 1)
{
    movQuizIntro.alpha = 1
    movQuizIntro.play()
}
}
```

What is the code and proper syntax you need  to write in order to go to frame 2 after the animation is done?

Answer (score 0):

`
    stop();
    movQuizIntro.stop();
    int frameCounter=0;

```
btnBond.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BondQuiz);
btnReg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Registrering);

function BondQuiz (evt:MouseEvent)
{
if (currentFrame == 1)
{
    movQuizIntro.alpha = 1
    movQuizIntro.play()

movQuizIntro.addEventListener(EventType.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
}

} 

// event handler function, runs every enter frame
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):Void
{
frameCounter++;
if(frameCounter > movQuizIntro.totalFrames)
{       
    //Place code here because you know the MovieClip finished playings
    //Go to desired frame       
}
}
```

`
I wrote this code outside of an editor nor did I get to compile, so the gist is there and may have some minor errors.
NOTE:This is just a quick way of doing this. If you want something more reusable/cleaner then you would want to consider subclassing or alternate Object Oriented tricks.

Answer (score 0):

In button event handler:

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
   ANIMATION_MC.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onFromeExit);
}

function onFrameExit(e:Event):void {
   if (ANIMATION_MC.currentFrame == SOME_FRAME) {
      ANIMATION_MC.removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onFromeExit);
      TARGET.gotoAndPlay(NEW_FRAME);
   }
}
```

And you can just use addFrameScript on ANIMATION_MC too.

Comment: You can use <code>this</code> in <code>onFrameExit</code> insted of ANIMATION_MC